# Нужна ли запятая после императива в примере?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, наклонение-глагола

Предложение:
"Зарегистрируйтесь как работодатель и сможете размещать вакансии"

Нужна ли запятая после "работодатель", учитывая, что после императива идет просто глагол, а не глагол в форме повелительного наклонения? Если нет, то почему? Если да, то почему?)

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зарегистрируйтесь как работодатель,  и сможете размещать вакансии.

Оборот с союзом КАК имеет значение "в качестве" и **не обособляется**.

Это сложносочиненное предложение с неоднородными односоставными предложениями (разные грамматические формы глагола), **поэтому запятая между предложениями ставится.**

Comment: Извините, придаточных нет, есть односоставные предложения в составе ССП.